# C# LINQ with foreach loop, Resets the value after loop exits

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have code like this, But Whenever am setting a value to the ConfigList, the value resets to default once the foreach loop exits.

```
using (var dbEntities = new DBEntities())
            {
                using (var dbContextTransaction = dbEntities.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var ConfigList = dbEntities.Configs.Where(y => y.DeviceId == deviceId).ToList();

                        if (ConfigList.Any())
                        {
                            foreach (InfoModel ConfigReceived in InfoModelCustom.Property)
                            {
                                ConfigList.Where(x => x.Id == ConfigReceived.Id
                                                    && x.PropertyId == ConfigReceived.PropertyId 
                                                    && x.GroupId == ConfigReceived.GroupId 
                                                    && x.TypeId == ConfigReceived.TypeId).FirstOrDefault().Value = ConfigReceived.Value;
                            }
                        }

                        dbEntities.SaveChanges();
                        dbContextTransaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is the value of `InfoModelCustom.Property.Count()`?

Comment: The count is 122 properties.

Comment: What makes you think the value resets to default? If you do a SQL Trace are you seeing any updates passing over the wire?

Comment: Hi @mjwills, When I was in loop the ConfigReceived.Value sets to the ConfigList collection, once all the iterations are complete its reached to the  dbEntities.SaveChanges(); then the value what we had sets wont be there instead the default value of the collection is appearing.

Comment: @mjwills the issue is before saving into the DB, SQL trance doesnt help here.

Comment: @Champ probably not a problem here, but `.FirstOrDefault().Value` bothers me... Also maybe do this in two steps, like `var config = ConfigList.Where().FirstOrDefault();` then `if(config != null){ config.Value = ConfigReceived.Value;}`. Then you can set a breakpoint in between, and see what you get in `config`.

Comment: @Rafalon Thats where the issue, Even I tried that, the ConfigReceived.Value sets to config.Value but after exiting from the loop after foreach iteration that assigned value gets resets.

Comment: @Champ did you check before and after `dbEntities.SaveChanges()`?

Comment: @Rafalon Yes, I did. The reset value gets inserted into the Database. that is not expected.

Comment: Could you perhaps write a unit test and show us some debug output?